# Access a Data Class Variable that's Being Stored in List - Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, data-class

I have a data class which takes in A LOT of variables. The object of this class is then stored in a mutable list. How do I search for the object that contains a specific user entered value and then return the associated variables of that object? For example, the user enters that they want to view variable d where variable a == "test" so I need to search the list to find the object where variable a equals "test" and then return the value of variable d of that object.

Below is example of code of what I currently have:

```
var exampleList = mutableListOf<Any>()

data class Example(val a: String, val b: String, val c: String, val d: String, val e: String,
               val f: String,val g: String, val h: String, val i: String, val j: String, val k: String,
               val l:String, val m: String, val n:String, val q: String, val r: String,
               val s: String, val t: String, val u: String, val v: String, val w: String,
               val x: String, val y: String, val z: String, val aa: String, val bb: String,
               val cc: String, val dd: String, val ee: String, val ff: String,
               val ruptureDisc: String, val ruptureDiscNotes: String, val remote: String, val gg: String,
               val hh: String, val ii: String, val jj: String, val kk: String, val ll: String,
               val mm: String, val nn: String, val oo: String, val pp: String, val qq:String,
               val rr: String)

fun addToList() {
        exampleList.add(
            Example(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
                12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
                23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                41, 42, 43, 44, 45)
        )
}
```

Comment: Looks like this data class should be replaced with a Map. Anyway, you can use `list.firstOrNull { it.a == "test" }`. If you know for sure there will be a match, drop the “OrNull” part.

Comment: I've tried this but I don't have access to "a" when calling "it" since it's stored in an object within the list. I've also explored Maps but a key can only store one variable and in this case, I need to store 44 variables to one key. I've looked at MultiMaps but I also couldn't get this to work as intended. I can't think of any other way to store multiple variables to one key short of storing them in a database. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `it` is the object within the list. Maybe you can share your exact code that isn’t working for you so we can point out what’s wrong with it.  Regarding Maps, I mean replace your data class with a Map so you would have a List of Maps. It’s kind of silly for a class to have so many public properties…it suggests you are not using DRY principles if you actually need to call each and every one of those by name elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I've added to the original question the companion object which initializes an empty list.

I've tried calling `exampleList.firstOrNull { it.a == "test" }` but I'm getting unresolved reference for "a".

I hear what you're saying about having a list of maps, but how would I put multiple variables to one key?

Comment: Your problem is using `mutableListOf<Any>()` instead of `mutableListOf<Example>()`. By doing that you are upcasting your Examples to the less specific Any class. If you use a list of maps, each map in the list holds one of the variables for each key, just like your list of examples, where each instance of Example has one value for each “key”. Alternatively, you could have a map of keys to lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter seems like a natural choice in this case, if you want to get items based on a certain conditions.

```
data class Example(val a: String, val b: String, val c: String, val d: String, val e: String)
var exampleList = mutableListOf<Example>()

fun addToList() {
    exampleList.add(Example("test", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
    exampleList.add(Example("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
}

addToList()    
val filteredList = exampleList.filter { it.a == "test" }
```